# Visualize igraph as inner and outer circle in R

Tags: r, layout, igraph

I am using the below code to generate a visNetwork in circular layout format (image attached below)

```
visNetwork(data$nodes,data$edges) %>% visIgraphLayout(layout="layout_in_circle")
```

I want to change the layout in a way such that, green nodes in inner circle and blue nodes in outer circle. Please let me know how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.
[image: Image Link]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to build the layout in igraph. You can feed it back into visNetwork at the end. I wasn't sure if you wanted the inner circle to connect to the outer. Both options are coded.

Call the green nodes `nodes1` and the blue nodes `nodes2`, created by subsetting your nodes matrix.

```
# edges within nodes1
edges1 <- edges[edges$from%in%nodes1$id & edges$to%in%nodes1$id, ] 
# edges within nodes2 
edges2 <- edges[edges$from%in%nodes2$id & edges$to%in%nodes2$id, ]
# edges within nodes1 or 2 = all edges if nodes1, 2 account for all nodes
edges12 <-edges[edges$from%in%c(nodes2$id,nodes1$id) &
  edges$to%in%c(nodes2$id,nodes1$id) , ]

igraph1 <- graph.data.frame(edges1, directed=F, vertices=nodes1)
igraph2 <- graph.data.frame(edges2, directed=F, vertices=nodes2)

# inner circle doesn't connect to outer:
igraph12a <- graph.data.frame(rbind(edges1, edges2), directed = F,
  vertices = rbind(nodes1, nodes2))

# inner circle can connect to outer:
igraph12b <- graph.data.frame(edges12, directed = F, vertices =
  rbind(nodes1, nodes2))

l1 = layout.circle(igraph1)
l2 = layout.circle(igraph2)
l12 = rbind(l1, l2 * 0.5) # 0.5 term scales the inner circle size

# plot both circles
plot.igraph(igraph1, layout = l1, rescale = F)
plot.igraph(igraph2, layout = l2*.5, add = T, rescale = F)

# plot both circles at once
plot.igraph(igraph12a, layout = l12, rescale = F)

# plot both circles with possible connections between them
plot.igraph(igraph12b, layout = l12, rescale = F)
```

Then, if you prefer it in visNetwork you can do that. Make sure you have an UPDATED version of visNetwork because the layout.norm with layoutMatrix capability is a recent addition:

```
visNetwork(nodes = rbind(nodes1, nodes2), edges = edges12) %>% 
  visIgraphLayout(layout="layout.norm", layoutMatrix = l12)
```

Of course, you'll want to  add node colors to all of these.

Comment: Thanks Jac. It worked with the code provided by you.

Comment: @hr02  If jac's response answered your question,  please accept is as a correct solution.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)